# dynamic urls in rails params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I am practicing to make API in rails. The api has currently only one end point which receives a url via get request. My routes are:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
    namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
      namespace :v1 do # resources :orders
        get "*link" => "application#parse_link"
      end
    end
end
```

My Application Controller Code:

```
require 'open-uri'

class Api::V1::ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    respond_to :json
  # protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def parse_link

        begin

            url = URI.parse(params[:link])
            doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).read)

        rescue
            redirect_to 'http://localhost:3000/'
        end

  end
end
```

When I send urls like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138538/dynamic-urls-in-rails-params
```

It works fine

But the following type of urls does not work:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/http://stackoverflow.com/
```

In this case, it splits the link and give me these params

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"link"=>"http:/stackoverflow", "format"=>"com"} permitted: true>
```

As you can see it splits the given url and save half of it in link param and the ".com" part in format params.

Thanks

Comment: url-escape special characters in the parameter: `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F`. If this isn't enough, escape the dot too.

Comment: But encoding will be done on the params.......The Param I am getting is already splitted......It is not a complete url

Comment: Nah, encode it __before__ you send the request. In the api client. Not the api server, of course.

Comment: Thanks but Oskar Laska's answer worked. Thanks alot

Comment: But why? If you want to create a method with takes a url param you would URI encode it and pass it in the query string. What you are creating is just a very greedy catchall that will mask 404 errors.

Comment: Ok. But how can I encode it before sending the request........User will write a random url and that will be passed in params then, how can I encode it before taht

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `defaults` to `constraints`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    namespace :api, constraints: { format: :json } do
      namespace :v1 do # resources :orders
        get "*link" => "application#parse_link"
      end
    end
end
```

Notice: it will constraint format to be json, not only set it as default. Rails treated `.com` at end of your URL as response type.